# How can i change the FlatList item background color when button is pressed in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

Let's suppose that i've a FlatList with some items, i press into one of them, then opens me another screen with the details of that item. Alright, so what i need is, after pressing the button called "Got it!" and goes into the back screen(FlatList screen), how can i set the background color to green in the row selected?

[So i click in one item of the FlatList, then it shows me another screen with the details of that item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG1wB.png)

[Once im in the Details screen, i press the button "Got it!", and it brings me back to the FlatList screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M83V.png)

[This is exactly what i need, set a background color only in the View shown in that item, if i press another item and do the same thing, it will be shown changed the background both of them, and so on...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfDcU.png)

NOTE: class Details and ProfileActivity are inside App.js as a childs.

```
 class ProfileActivity extends Component
 {
GetFlatListItem (Description, Tutorial, Imagen, Title) {

Alert.alert(Description);
this.props.navigation.navigate('Fourth', {Tutorial, Imagen, Title});
}
return(
     <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>
     <Button title="Logout" onPress={ () => goBack(null) } />
        <Text style = {styles.TextComponentStyle}> { this.props.navigation.state.params.Email } </Text>


      <FlatList

                data={ this.state.dataSource }

                ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}

                renderItem={({item}) => <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}> <Text style={styles.points}>+ {item.points}</Text> 
                                            <Text style={styles.flatview} onPress={this.GetFlatListItem.bind
                                            (this, item.description, item.tutorial, item.image, item.title)} >{item.title}</Text></View>}

                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}

               />
     </View>
  );
class Details extends Component{
onPress = () => {
this.setState({
  const {goBack} =this.props.navigation;
})
}
return(
     <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>

     <TouchableHighlight
     style={styles.buttonStyle}
     onPress={this.onPress}
    >
     <Text> Got it! </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>

        <Text style = {styles.TextComponentStyle}> { this.props.navigation.state.params.Title } </Text>
         <Image
      style={{width: 66, height: 58}}
      source={{uri: this.props.navigation.state.params.Imagen}}
    />
    <Text style = {styles.TextComponentStyle}> { this.props.navigation.state.params.Tutorial } </Text>
     </View>
  );
}
export default MainProject = createStackNavigator(
{
First: { screen: App },

Second: { screen: ProfileActivity },

Fourth: { screen: Details }

});
```

What i think is pass some values to the method onPress() in Details class, but i don't know which one exactly and how. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You will have to create this.state.someArrayName and copy from `this.props.navigation.state.params` and add `backgroundColor` key to each object and add your color. Apply that color to your items' view background color. *{{backgroundColor : item.backgroundColor}}
- Create a function `changeColor` to change the color of `backgroundColor`
- In your `GetFlatListItem` function, pass that function to detail view
- On Detail View, call that `changeColor` function. `this.props. changeColor()` when you tap `Got it` button.

Comment: Hi, the thing is that if the “Got it!” button is not pressed, the colour needs to be the same.